# JSF Refresh page after login returns to login page

Tags: java, security, jsf, jsf-2, wildfly

I'm using container managed security in my JSF application. I am able to login successfully and get to my protected area. If I hit the browser refresh though I go back to my login page. From what I can deduce, for some reason the authenticated session is being lost which is causing me to be redirected to the login page.

So to make sure you understand my issue:
1) Go to protected area, login page presented
2) Put credentials and click login
3) Authenticated and protected jsf page presented
4) hit refresh, login page shows up.

I logged the request session id's and they are changing.

**web.xml (relevant parts)**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mappings/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>IESI Security Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/mappings/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>IESI</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>ApplicationRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/index.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/logout.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>IESI</role-name>
</security-role>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

**Authenticator**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Authenticator
{
   private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Authenticator.class);

   private String username;

   private String password;

   public String getUsername()
   {
      return username;
   }

   public void setUsername(String username)
   {
      this.username = username;
   }

   public String getPassword()
   {
      return password;
   }

   public void setPassword(String password)
   {
      this.password = password;
   }

   public String login()
   {
      final FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
      final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();

      try
      {
         final Principal userPrincipal = request.getUserPrincipal();
         if (userPrincipal != null)
         {
            request.logout();
         }
         request.login(username, password);
         context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("user", request.getUserPrincipal());

         final Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();  
         LOGGER.debug("Authenticated user: " + principal.getName());

         if(request.isUserInRole("IESI"))
         {  
              return "/mappings/mappings.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";  
         }
         else
         {  
              return "login";  
         } 
      }
      catch (final ServletException e)
      {
         context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Login failed!", null));
         return "login";
      }
   }

   public String logout()
   {
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
      return "login";
   }
```

**PhaseListener**

```
public class AuthorizationListener
implements PhaseListener
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Override
   public void afterPhase(final PhaseEvent event)
   {

      final FacesContext facesContext = event.getFacesContext();
      final String currentPage = facesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId();

      final boolean isLoginPage = (currentPage.lastIndexOf("index.xhtml") > -1);
      final HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);

      if (session == null)
      {
         final NavigationHandler nh = facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
         nh.handleNavigation(facesContext, null, "login");
      }
      else
      {
         final Object currentUser = session.getAttribute("user");

         if (!isLoginPage && ((currentUser == null) || (currentUser == "")))
         {
            System.out.println("PHASE: USER IS NULL");
            final NavigationHandler nh = facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
            nh.handleNavigation(facesContext, null, "login");
         }
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void beforePhase(final PhaseEvent event)
   {

   }

   @Override
   public PhaseId getPhaseId()
   {
      return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;
   }
}
```

Comment: When you "hit refresh", what address is selected in the browser? (/login or /mappings...)

Comment: /mappings/...... is the url in the browser.

Comment: Where are you importing the `@SessionScoped` annotation from? Also confirm that your JSESSION_ID stays consistent across all the requests

Comment: `import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;`
I am suspecting the JSESSION_ID is not consistent.

Comment: I switched the tracking mode to URL. When I login the first time I get this jsessionId: `http://localhost:8080/iesi/mappings/mappings.xhtml;jsessionid=LFAO3xjuiSxW5UyoDEA9pa84.ws-camtl-kyriv`
When I hit refresh it stays the same but login page shows up, click login  again and get a new jsessionid; `http://localhost:8080/iesi/mappings/mappings.xhtml;jsessionid=fk4cBPGIMrzqo7BLxAVO4-ya.ws-camtl-kyriv`

Comment: That phase listener is strange. You shouldn't have the need for it if you aren't using homegrown authorization. Get rid of it. As to changing session ID everytime, try cleaning all cookies in browser. WildFly is known to have trouble with session cookies left behind by other containers (e.g. Tomcat) on same domain.

Comment: Removed it as per your request. Flushed all the cookies (even though I only use Wildfly) and still the same result.

Comment: looks like its an issue with undertow: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3448